# Turn off register_globals through a php file

Tags: php

I want to know how can I turn off the register_globals for a single php file? Like is there any code which is capable of turning off the register_globals feature in configuration file?

Comment: Google "register_globals", first result. Did you try that?

Comment: I tried evry code but none seem to work.

Comment: @Sanks: I'm pretty sure your website is *not* google.com. The field in your profile is optional so just leave it empty

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP as an Apache module, you can put a directive in an .htaccess file (or httpd.conf), restricted to the file or files you want:

```
<FilesMatch "^foo\.php$">
php_flag register_globals off
</FilesMatch>
```

Other SAPIs have other mechanisms. CGI/FPM can use a per-directory php.ini.

The option cannot, however, be disabled in a PHP script (at runtime).

Comment: I dont have permissions to edit .htaccess file. I want code for a php script..

Comment: @Sanks Have you read the last phrase?

Answer (score 0):

It is **impossible** do to so through in a PHP script itself. When the first line is executed the globals have already been created. The only thing you could do is unsetting them before doing anything else:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $var => $value) { unset($GLOBALS[$var]); }
```

However, if your ISP has register_globals enabled and doesn't even allow you to use .htaccess you should better look for a new one.